# WCF Contracts without the annotations

Tags: c#, wcf

I was wondering if there is any way to define a WCF Contract class without using the [DataContract] and [DataMember] annotation. The reason is that domain model we currently have is fairly clean so we would like to keep it this way. Whats the best practice here? Create a Transfer object and copy the domain model object into a transfer object (that has the required annotations and is the Contract transfered between Client and Server)? Or somehow not annotate the object model and specify the contract in a different way.

Comment: Thanks - I did search for a while before posting and the "Related Questions" feature of SO didn't help. Looking at the answers in the other post I would like my question to remain open cause some of the questions I have in the comments below are still not answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not add *any* serialization attributes to your class, and use it as part of a WCF service contract method, WCF will use the default serialization rules to produce a data contract anyway. This means that the class will implicitly become a `[DataContract]` every **public property** that has **both** a `get` and `set` accessor will implicitly become a `[DataMember]`.

The only time you *need* to apply the attributes is if you want to override the default behavior, e.g. hiding some attributes, applying namespaces, etc. It's generally considered good practice to do so anyway, because relying on the default behavior might get you in trouble later. (It also makes it explicit that your class is meant for use by WCF). But it's not strictly required, as long as the default behavior meets your needs.

---

In response to your follow-up:

As far as I know there's no completely external way to change the serialization behavior of the `DataContractSerializer` for a given class; every option requires at least some level of attribution on the class being serialized. As @Yair Nevet describes below, my preferred method for turning existing domain objects into data contracts is the `MetadataType` attribute.

Alternatively, you can bypass the whole issue by doing what you suggested in your question: *don't* serialize your domain objects, but create custom DTO objects and serialize them. I tend to do this whenever I'm using the Entity Framework, for example, because serializing those can be tricky. This is also a good approach to take if your domain objects have lots of behaviors built into them -- you get a clear separation of "data being passed around" vs. "objects participating in my business logic."

You often end up with lots of redundant code, but it does achieve your goal of zero changes to your existing objects.

Comment: OK - so its like JSON Serialization that uses the same attributes then. But still if I do need to have a custom serializer for say a class called Person is there any way to achieve this WITHOUT changing anything in the Person class?

Comment: Not that I know of. If the default serialization isn't appropriate, you need to make at least *some* changes to your original class definition. The one given in @Yair's aswer is the way I usually go about it, because it's the smallest footprint.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `MetadataType` attribute and a metadata model class in order to separate the annotations from your model.

For example:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MyModelMetadata))]
public class MyModel : MyModelBase {
  ... /* the current model code */
}

[DataContract]
public class MyModelMetadata {
    [DataMember] 
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate further please? What its the purpose of the partial class related to my question?

Comment: Look at my updated answer.

Comment: Well I still need to amend my domain model to achieve this. This is not always possible or desirable. I m looking for a solution that leaves the domain model unchanged. But thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

WCF is capable of serializing your objects without the attributes. The attributes are there to allow for customization. For example, the two classes will serialize identically by the [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx):

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Customer
{
    [DataMember] public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

---

It is worth mentioning that you really should mark your class with the attributes. They aren't as "messy" as you think. It will actually save you from headache in the future. For example:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Customer")]
public class Customer
{
    [DataMember(Name = "FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

In the previous code sample, I explicitly set the names of the class and members. This will allow me to refactor the names without breaking consumers code. So, if someone decides that my class should be named *CustomerDetail* instead of *Customer*, I can still leave the name as *Customer* so that consumers of my service continue to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot - What if I do need to have a custom serializer for say a class called Person is there any way to achieve this WITHOUT changing anything in the Person class?

Comment: If you are going to opt to create a custom serializer in lieu of the `DataContractSerializer`, then simply build in some default behavior, just like the `DataContractSerializer` does. The serializer should be able to handle your classes whether or not the attributes are there.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use DTOs.  Make a separate class that has everything that is needed to serialize your objects.  Then project your domain model on to the DTO.  You could use something like AutoMapper to make this process a little easier.

**Regarding Performance**

Unless you have hundreds, probably thousands, or objects or a very large number of properties per class, the act of converting to and from DTOs probably isn't that much performance overhead.

If you are using something like EF, and you are not serializing every property, you might even be able to reduce some overhead by projecting your EF query directly on to  your DTOs.

This is kind of a dramatic case, but I had (poorly designed) database models with 50+ properties per type.  By changing to DTOs that only have the 10-15 properties I cared about, I was able to almost double the performance of a WCF service.

Comment: Yeah - Thats what I was thinking about as well. Just wanted to now if there is an built-in alternative for better performance (to avoid the overhead of converting from/to DTOs)